# Declaring multiple variables at once in a function

Tags: c, declaration, function-parameter

If `int a, b, c;` is a valid declaration

Why not `int f(int a, b, c)`?

Comment: Just because that's how the language is defined.

Comment: "As it currently stands, this question is not a good fit for our Q&A format. We expect answers to be supported by facts, references, or specific expertise, but this question will likely solicit debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion."

Comment: In olden days, you could write `int f() int a,b,c; {...}`

Comment: @JimBalter Actually `int f(a,b,c) int a, b, c; ... `

Comment: @MatsPetersson Like I said, olden ... so olden that I forgot, despite having spent years writing that stuff.

Comment: " I fail to see what could be the reason for not implementing it" -- And you are apparently the sort of person who thinks that your inability to see something is a virtue. In fact it would make the language very difficult to parse, because b might be either a type or a variable name.

Comment: My powers of deduction are very good, my dear Watson-like David. I didn't make my deduction from your question but rather from your *assertion* ... the one I quoted. There are other things that I deduce from your acceptance of an "answer" that does not remotely answer the question that you asked.

Comment: You don't have a good grasp of the meaning of "exactly", nor of what quote marks are for. The "answer" you accepted doesn't even mention a committee, nor the motivations behind the standard --as I said, it does not remotely answer the question you asked, "All-Bran".

Comment: @JimBalter "Treat others with the same respect you’d want them to treat you. We’re all here to learn together. Be tolerant of others who may not know everything you know. Bring your sense of humor."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard called `ANSI C` (Also known as `ISO C`) defines one of the most widely followed standards of C. It defines functions to be declared as `int f(int a, int b, int c)` and not as `int f(int a, b, c)`. Other standards of C like `C99` and `C11` goes for the same style. Only `K & R C` standard for function definition is slightly different. In it you define the function f() as follows,

```
int f(a , b, c)
int a,b,c;
{ 
   /* Body of function */
}
```

Comment: a) That doesn't answer the question. b) In the K&R syntax (which was still legal in C89), the types of parameters are only known inside the function ... it's not a prototype.